# why are some of the keyring file becoming unusable after a reboot

Tags: gnome3, ubuntu-22.04, gnome-keyring

Recently my Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) start asking me to recreate the default keyring after reboot. So I open the keyring files to see if anything goes wrong:

Several keyring files were found under `~/.local/share/keyring`:

```
s:~/.local/share/keyrings$ ls -l
total 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peng peng    8 Nov 18 20:52 default
-rw------- 1 peng peng 9564 Nov 10 17:31 Default_keyring.keyring
-rw------- 1 peng peng 9033 Nov 18 19:53 Fallback.keyring
-rw------- 1 peng peng  549 Nov 16 11:06 login.keyring
-rw------- 1 peng peng  207 Sep 22 13:18 user.keystore
```

Since the Default_keyring.keyring is unencrypted, I'm able to open it with a text editor:

```
[keyring]
display-name=Default keyring
ctime=1700091188
mtime=0
lock-on-idle=false
lock-after=false

[2]
item-type=0
display-name=Chromium Safe Storage
secret=WyNXm3K+MQwSOUXt3vmK7Q==
mtime=1700091188
ctime=1700091188

[2:attribute0]
name=application
type=string
value=chromium

[2:attribute1]
name=xdg:schema
type=string
value=chrome_libsecret_os_crypt_password_v2

[1]
item-type=0
display-name=Chrome Safe Storage Control
secret=The meaning of life
mtime=1700091188
ctime=1700091188

[1:attribute0]
name=explanation
type=string
value=Because of quirks in the gnome libsecret API, Chrome needs to store a dummy entry to guarantee that this keyring was properly unlocked. More details at http://crbug.com/660005.

[1:attribute1]
name=xdg:schema
type=string
value=_chrome_dummy_schema_for_unlocking
```

Everything looks completely normal, yet when I open the `Passwords and Keys` application shipped with Ubuntu, none of these keyring files are visible.

What may cause Ubuntu to ignore them? And what should I do to import them back?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Does this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1689825) help? See also this derived [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931780/passwords-missing-from-seahorse-passwords-and-keys).

Comment: @harrymc thanks a lot, kind of ... but due to dependencies I can't purge it at the moment